# How to add elements to a triplet matrix using CHOLMOD?

Tags: c++, libraries, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, suitesparse

Can anyone please give me a simple example of how to add elements to a triplet matrix using [CHOLMOD](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/cholmod/).

I have tried something like this:

```
cholmod_triplet *A;
int k;

void add_A_entry(int r, int c, double x)
{
    ((int*)A->i)[k] = r;
    ((int*)A->j)[k] = c;
    ((double*)A->x)[k] = x;
    k++;
}

int main()
{
    k = 0;
    cholmod_common com;
    cholmod_start(&com);

    A = cholmod_allocate_triplet(202, 202, 202*202, -1, CHOLMOD_REAL, &com);
    add_A_entry(2, 2, 1.);
    add_A_entry(4, 1, 2.);
    add_A_entry(2, 10, -1.);

    cholmod_print_triplet(A, "A", &com);

    cholmod_finish(&com);
    return 0;
}
```

However, this doesn't add any elements to the matrix. I simply get the output:

```
CHOLMOD triplet: A:  202-by-202, nz 0, lower.  OK
```

Of course, I have tried to find the solution both by searching and in the [CHOLMOD documentation](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/cholmod/CHOLMOD/Doc/UserGuide.pdf), but I found no help.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that it does not add elements to the matrix? Where is k initialized? is it a global variable?

Comment: If I for example print the matrix elements by
    cholmod_print_triplet(A, "Triplet", &com);
it prints a matrix of zeros.

The matrix and the variable k is defined in the scope of a class, but yes, for simplicity let's say they are global variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`cholmod_allocate_triplet()` sets `A->nzmax`, which in your case is 202*202. That just defines the space available to add triplets. The actual number of triplets in the matrix is `A->nnz`, which gets set to zero by `cholmod_allocate_triplet()`.

The `A->nnz` should be used instead of your variable `k`.

Tim Davis (CHOLMOD author)

Comment: So simple, yet so difficult to figure out. Thanks a lot!